# Using WebFaultException from IErrorHandler

Tags: json, wcf, ierrorhandler

If I derive all of my exceptions from `WebFaultException`, and throw them directly from my services, the StatusCode set in the `WebFaultException` gets passed to the client. I'd rather not have to do that, since I'd rather throw generic exceptions like `NotImplementedException`, from my code.

I've set up an IErrorHandler, with the expectation that I'd be able to catch exceptions like `NotImplementedException`, and then just do the conversion to a `WebFaultException` there.

My code looks like this:

```
public class HTTPBindingErrorHandler: IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception exception, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {
        if (exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            WebFaultException wfe = new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
            MessageFault mf = wfe.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, mf, wfe.Action);
        }
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When stepping through, I see that I'm getting to the code in ProvideFault, but the Status returned to the client is 400, not 501. Additionally, the body is:

```
<Fault
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
    <Code>
        <Value>Receiver</Value>
        <Subcode>
            <Value
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2009/WebFault">a:NotImplemented
            </Value>
        </Subcode>
    </Code>
    <Reason>
        <Text xml:lang="en-US">Not Implemented</Text>
    </Reason>
</Fault>
```

1. Why isn't the correct status code being returned?
2. Why isn't the body
   in json?

Addition:
I've tried the recommendation of setting AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = false to the webhttpbehavior, but it still does not work. I'm self hosting, but I don't think that should make the difference. Here is the code I use to set up the service:

```
Uri newUri = new Uri(info.baseURI, info.Path);
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(info.Type, newUri);
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.InheritedFromHost;


ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(info.Interface, binding, newUri);
ep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { 
    DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = false } );
ep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpCors.CorsSupportBehavior());
ep.Behaviors.Add(new HTTPBindingErrorBehavior());
```